# How to pass configuration environnement variable inside my plugin with Strapi v3

Tags: reactjs, admin, strapi

I need help to pass config inside my .env to my file inside my plugin. My plugin is inside my Strapi admin. So, this is my sample of code :

My Environnement File

```
// .env

JUST_A_TEST=JUSTATEST
```

My Plugin File where i want to use my Env

```
// ./plugins/myplugin/admin/src/containers/HomePage/index.js

const test  = process.env.JUST_A_TEST // not work
const test2 = strapi.plugins.myplugin.JUST_A_TEST // not work
const test3 = JUST_A_TEST // not work
```

I have tried to add config inside admin

```
// ./admin/admin.config.js

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
   webpack: (config, webpack) => {
      config.plugins.push(
         new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'JUST_A_TEST ': env('JUST_A_TEST '),
         })
      )
      return config
   }
})
```

I just don't understand why i don't receive environnement variable inside my plugin.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you try to log `process.env.JUST_A_TEST` if it works?

Comment: Yes but nothing 